# Python Multiplying and Adding values in array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sum a multiple of values in my array.  Here's what I have:

```
x = ['a', 2, 5, 10],['b', 3, 4, 11], ['c', 4, 2, 12], ['d', 5, 1, 13]
```

I want to multiply the 2nd and 3rd value of each row and then add all the products together:

```
(2*5) + (3*4) + (4*2) + (5*1)
```

I also need this to be able to work for an indefinite number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(map(lambda item: item[1]*item[2], x))
```

Works for any number of rows. What we are doing here is:

1. define a lambda to multiply 2nd and 3rd element of a row.
2. Apply the lambda for each row
3. Sum the result

Since we are making use of iterator here, memory requirement is low even for a large number of rows.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
result = 0

for arr in x:
    result += arr[1] + arr[2]

print (result)
```

But also you can use numpy in future for operation on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it functionally:

```
x = ['a', 2, 5, 10],['b', 3, 4, 11], ['c', 4, 2, 12], ['d', 5, 1, 13]
from operator import itemgetter, mul
from itertools import starmap, imap

print(sum(starmap(mul, imap(itemgetter(1, 2), x))))
35
```

Or a mix of functional and unpacking:

```
print(sum(a * b for a, b in  imap(itemgetter(1, 2), x)))
35
```

Just unpacking:

```
print(sum(a * b for _, a, b, _ in x))
```

Or indexing:

```
print(sum(sub[1] * sub[2] for sub in x))
```

If speed is your main concern and unpacking is possible then `sum(a * b for _, a, b, _ in x)` should be the fastest followed by `sum(sub[1] * sub[2] for sub in x)`
 and using a list will actually be faster but obviously use more memory.

Comment: Unpacking solution becomes ugly if there are more elements in each row. Looks ok for 4 elements.

Comment: @helloV, if there were more than a few you would not use it, I provided three other methods including probably the fastest possible ways to do it, using a lambda is expensive